# How many way to arrange colored blocks in a cube

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> I have $42$ blocks ($14$ red, $14$ blue, & $14$ white). How many different ways can these blocks be arranged in a $2\times 3 \times 7$ cube?

I have tried using $\displaystyle\frac{42!}{(42-3)!}$ but I am not confident that this is correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: What about motions of the "cube"?

Comment: Motion is not meaningful for this problem.